# Typescript: @ts-ignore Not Working on Let Variable That's Not Reassigned?

Tags: typescript

**BACKSTORY (feel free to skip to the problem)**

I'm trying to destructure a response from an Apollo `useLazyQuery`, and then change one variable.  Without Typescript, it would be two simple lines:

```
 let [someFunction, { data, loading }] = useLazyQuery(QUERY);
 data = 'whatever'
```

However, that offends Typescript, because I'm making all the variables `let` even though most don't change.  So, I changed the code to destrucure *most* of the response as constant, with a single exception:

```
 const stuff = useLazyQuery(QUERY);
 let [_, { data }] = stuff; // get one variable as a non-constant
 const [someFunction, { loading }] = stuff; // get the rest as constants
```

The problem is, I'm still getting TypeScript errors/warnings:

> 77:8  warning  '_' is assigned a value but never used                                                                                                                    no-unused-vars

> 77:8  error    '_' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead                                                                                                              prefer-const

Of course, `_` is just a placeholder to help me destructure `data`, so it's not supposed to be re-assigned ... but it is needed on the `let` line to make the destructuring work.

**PROBLEM**

I would have thought I could tell Typescript "don't worry about `_`, just ignore it" by adding an `@ts-ignore` comment:

```
 const stuff = useLazyQuery(QUERY);
 // @ts-ignore
 let [_, { data }] = stuff; // get one variable as a non-constant
 const [someFunction, { loading }] = stuff; // get the rest as constants
```

But all that does is add a new warning about how I should use `@ts-expect-error` instead of `@ts-ignore` ... it doesn't get rid of the warning/error about my `_` variable.

**QUESTIONS (Two Related Ones)**

1. I thought `@ts-ignore` ignored all warnings/errors on the next line; can anyone explain how Typescript decides which warnings/errors `@ts-ignore` actually ignores, and which it doesn't?
2. Can anyone explain how I can make Typescript stop complaining about `'_' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead` error (using `@ts-ignore` or anything else) ... without giving up on basic language features like destructuring?

Comment: These are eslint errors right? You have an es lint config? mind sharing it here?

Comment: Oh, I thought they were coming from Typescript!  But now that you mention it, both my ESLint and TS errors come in through `[plugin:vite-plugin-eslint]`, so I must have been confusing them ... and that explains why my `@ts-ignore` isn't working.  Could you please provide an answer to the effect of "`@ts-ignore` doesn't fix ES Lint errors, dummy" and I'll happily accept it?

Comment: P.S. `// eslint-disable-next-line` *does* fix the error! (Perhaps that can be included in the answer?)

Comment: I guess you found the answer your self :P Is this still a valid question? Then i can answer, with softer language ofcourse. If not then idk what to do

Comment: Heh, yeah, thanks; your earlier comment led me to it :)

Comment: I think it's still valid; while I made a very dumb mistake, I could see others possibly making the same dumb mistake, so this question/answer might still help others.  Thanks again!

Comment: i figured, wrote an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarification : above errors are coming from es-lint and not TS itself.
You will need to disable that.

You can use:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
 let [_, { data }] = stuff;
```

or

```
 let [_, { data }] = stuff; // eslint-disable-line
```